# How to include a subdirectory filter on the Activity feed?

Tags: facebook, android-activity, feed

Does anyone know how to use filter "Activity Feed" ?

For instance on [this page](http://www.alexandra-lloyd.com/fr/ventes.php) I want to display only french entries (links on the website that include the subdirectory /fr/):

The problem is if I put the filter="/fr" then nothing is displayed whereas they exist.

Here is the code:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:activity site="www.alexandra-lloyd.com" width="428" height="260" header="true" font="verdana" border_color="" recommendations="true" filter="/fr"></fb:activity>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's no filtering in that free Activity Feed plugin.  You will need to write your own to do filtering.  Start here:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its the same issue but it appears there are more people with the same issue.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/325192644188145/?browse=search_4f1e10ebdb8141869509439